# What does this sentence mean? ‘Er musste dringend weg.’

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following sentence means  ‘He had to go away urgently’, but where is the verb **go** in the sentence? It seems the sentence lacks the verb **go**.

> Er musste dringend weg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb is [*wegmüssen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wegmuessen) here, that's why there's no need of *go*. (Like: *losfahren* => *Er fuhr sofort los.*)

Sometimes *müssen* is like a state indicator in German language, like *must be*; in spite of English where *must* is an auxiliary verb. In my opinion, the best English fit would be

> He must be off, urgently. (He had to be off, urgently.)

Comment: Actually this makes complete sense. I would still argue that you can view it as an ellipsis, because *wegmüssen* (compound verb) and *weggehen müssen* (ellipsis if you leave out *gehen*) both work in the example sentence, but this is a better answer than mine I think. It's both, but yours is the obvious way to interpret the sentence, mine is less straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it absolutely lacks the verb *to go*. If you want, it could also be rendered as:

> Er musste dringend weggehen.

or

> Er musste dringend gehen.

It's an example of **ellipsis**, the rhetoric device whereby parts of a sentence are omitted.

Using an ellipsis is not a question of grammar, but of semantics. You can generally do it if the context makes clear the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Certainly +1, but it's worth noting that the sentence doesn't necessarily apply "to go / gehen". Perhaps, he had to drive away, run away. Though, "gehen" in a universal meaning (not related to walking) is the most common one.

Comment: Good point, and an opportunity to learn about [Verben der Bewegung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_der_Bewegung) (verbs of movement), Where you build the perfect with *sein* instead of *haben*. I.e. ich bin gegangen/gefahren/geradelt.

Answer (score 0):

The translation reads: 'He had to [go] away urgently’.

The "go" (verb gehen in German), in brackets, is "understood" in this context. That is to say that "weg" is an abbreviation for weggehen.